# How to align text according to above text in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div of width 50vw wide, containing some text, with some other text below that I want aligned to the right, as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/hadr4ytt/1/

Here is the current CSS:

```
div {
  width:50vw;
  margin-left:7.4vw;
  } 

 h3{
   text-align:right;
 }
```

I was wondering if it was possible to align the `h3` text so that the end character is always lined up to the end character of the `h2` text. Also, if the `h2` text was to be expanded so that it spanned multiple lines, is it possible to line up the end character of `h3` with the right most character of `h2` (the text is not justified so depending on the word length different lines will have different lengths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the outer div must remain at 50vw, the solution is to add a new element inside the div that you can align the headers to.

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  margin-left: 7.4vw;
}

hgroup {
  display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <hgroup>
    <h2>
      Some text here.
    </h2>

    <h3>
      Other text here
    </h3>
  </hgroup>
</div>
```

Edit: Oh, my apologies to @David Hedlund, who already posted a demo in a comment. I didn't see that before posting my answer.

Comment: This works good enough for me to accept it as an answer. If you could edit your answer to suggest how I could make h3 align to the outermost character in h2 (try `<h2>
      Some text here that spans across two lines as it is too big to see.
    </h2>` on JS fiddle and you will see what I mean. But other than that thank you!

Comment: I tested various things, such as `width:fit-content` for the hgroup, but no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Added `display: inline-block;` to the div.

```css
div {
  margin-left: 7.4vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    Some text here
  </h2>

  <h3>
    Other text here
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to keep the positioning of `h2` the same, and move `h3` not the other way around

Comment: This doesn't seem to be making any difference for me when I update it on the JSfiddle unless I remove the width: 50vw

Comment: I removed width also.

Comment: @Anon1231123: This is because the div in the fiddle has a fixed width. The point with using `inline-block` is (simplified) that the width is determined by its content. If you still need a fixed width, then you need to wrap the headers in a container that has inline-block. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bckqvnv/2/).

Comment: @Anon1231123 So the div must be 50vw wide, but the h3 has to be right-aligned to the h2 anyway? That wasn't very clear. I'm not sure that can be done without adding additional HTML around the two h's inside the div.

Comment: @MrLister yes that is correct, my apologies for it not being clear.

Comment: @DavidHedlund That works best so far, but when the text goes onto a different line, is it possible to still keep the end of the h3 character aligned with the outermost h2 character? Or would I require javascript or something

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand all you need is to add `text-align: right;` to a h2 element and that will give you your desired result.

Comment: I want to keep the positioning of `h2` the same and move `h3` not the other way around, else with short text it gets moved to near the centre of the page instead of 7.4vw from the left